# Can't make height: 50%

Tags: css, height

I'm trying to have two divs above and below each other, both of which take up 50% of the screen.

My site is [here](http://sebastiansalek.com/depfinder/) and the divs in question are `#intro` and `#services`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Add `html,body{height:100%;}`

Comment: Argh, I knew I forgot something! That did it. Thanks.

Comment: Note: All parent elements of the elements `#intro` and `#services` has to have the height set to work.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento - No, not all parents, just at least one. But in this case since we're dealing with the height of the viewport and percentages, only the html and body elements must have a height set.

Comment: @j08691 Ranges from "webbrowser" (engine, eg. Gecko, Trident, Webkit, etc) to "webbrowser" and "doctype" to "doctype". > Note: this question is a duplicate and has been asked numerous times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `html,body{height:100%;}` to your code.